# how to format birthday?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I'm having trouble formatting the birthday date in the format 2021-04-13T00:00:00.000Z the date is sent correctly, but after this formatting it always has 1 day less. Can anyone help?

```
export function format(date): string {
  const mydate = new Date(date);
  return new Intl.DateTimeFormat().format(mydate);
}
```

Comment: add one day and then format ? :-p

Comment: Your starting date is expressed as a UTC date at midnight. If you run your code somewhere west of UTC, and express the date in your local time zone, then it will show as one day earlier.

Comment: @MuhammadUsman worst thing you could do.

Comment: @Pointy so how could I solve this? have any tips?

Comment: Well you could use `date.getUTCMonth()` and `date.getUTCDay()` to get the month and day reckoning from UTC time instead of your local time.

Comment: As @Pointy already pointed out, you should generally work with UTC in order to avoid localization-issues like the one you are experiencing. You can always translate UTC to local time if needed..

Answer (score 2):

Using the basic Date methods `.getUTCYear()`, `.getUTCMonth()`, and `.getUTCDay()` will enable you to get the date as it appears in your UTC-relative source string. As noted in a comment, your apparent date when rendered in your *local* time zone is one day earlier, as is correct for time zones west of UTC.

You can still make use of `Intl.DateTimeFormat()` if you pass in an option to use UTC as the time zone:

```
return new Intl.DateTimeFormat("pt-BR", { timeZone: "UTC" }).format(dateInput);
```

However, that's not supported by IE11 (if that's important to you).

Comment: Here's the documentation on [DateTimeFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat).